# Copy locust file into volume via YML in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, locust

I have a yml file that I took from a github repository.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: scripts-cm
data:
  locustfile.py: |
    from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task


    class UserTasks(TaskSet):

        @task
        def index(self):
            self.client.get("/")

        @task
        def stats(self):
            self.client.get("/stats/requests")


    class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
        task_set = UserTasks
```

But I don't want to set my configure management to do this as I have a separate locustfile.py and it is quite big. Is there a way to copy the file in the data attribute instead? or I have to use cat command?

Comment: Have you tried to create your configmap like this: `$ kubectl create configmap scripts-cm --from-file=locusts.py`?

Comment: it says `configmap/scripts-cm created` but I can't find it in the folder

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to copy the file in the data attribute instead?

Yes there is. You can create a `configMap` from a file and mount this configMap as a Volume to a `Pod`. I've prepared an example to show you the whole process.

Let's assume that you have your `locustfile.py` with only the Python script:

```py
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task


class UserTasks(TaskSet):

    @task
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @task
    def stats(self):
        self.client.get("/stats/requests")


class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserTasks
```

You will need to create a `configMap` from this file with following command:

- `$ kubectl create configmap scripts-cm --from-file=locustfile.py`

After that you can mount this `configMap` as a `Volume` like in the example below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ubuntu
      image: ubuntu
      command: 
      - sleep 
      - "infinity" 
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /app/ # <-- where you would like to mount your files from a configMap 
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: scripts-cm # <-- name of your configMap
  restartPolicy: Never
```

You can then check if your files are placed correctly in the `/app` directory:

- `$ kubectl exec -it ubuntu -- ls /app/`

```sh
locustfile.py
```

> A tip!
>
> You can add multiple files to a `configMap` by
>
> - `--from-file=one.py --from-file=two.py ...`
>
> You can also run `--from-file=.` (use all the files from directory).

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Configure pod container: Configure pod configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/)*